# Meaning of となつかしむなり in this context?

Tags: grammar, meaning

End of chapter 33 of the manga 課長島耕作.

> 先斗町 袖より合うも 春の夜の 他生の縁と なつかしむなり

先斗町 is the setting of the chapter.

I guess 春の夜 doesn't differ from its dictionary entry:

> short spring night

I know `袖より合うも他生の縁` is a variation of the proverb `袖すり合うも他生の縁` (although I don't really get the difference with the より and すり.)

What I'm not understanding is the last part `となつかしむなり`

[image]

Comment: I might be wrong, but as for the use of より instead of すり, it might be a [*kakekotoba*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakekotoba) for 寄り合い ("gathering; meet-up").

Answer (score 2):

> ...となつかしむなり

と is quotative particle.

懐かしむ{なつかしむ} is verb meaning "to recall fondly".

I think that this なり could be form of (originally) Evidential *nar-* which originally had meanings: (1) "it sounds as if somebody does, one can hear somebody do", (2) "it is said/reported that somebody does". It should not be mistaken with homophonous Old/Middle/Classical Japanese copula *nar-* (← *ni ar-*). Evidential *nar-* is supposedly contraction of **na* "sound" + *ar-* "to exist", so it conjugates analogically to classical verb [あり](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9C%89%E3%82%8A) (ancestor of modern ある).
(Neither of them should be confused with 成る{なる} "to become" and 鳴る{なる} "to sound, to ring, to roar".)

After mediaeval times, this なり was used only in poetry and literary language, and it functions as exclamation.

Comment: Who do you think is the subject of 懐かしむ? If it's the author himself ("I"), "It sounds like I recall" and "It's said that I recall" both make little sense here. According to [this](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A) and [this](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A-590074), this type of なり can be used to simply add an 詠嘆 (exclamatory) mood after the Edo period, so I feel this could be just 懐かしむことだよ or 懐かしむのだ.

Comment: The latter entry says: "この「なり」は、中世以降は、歌語・文章語にだけ用いられた。「詠嘆」と説かれて、近世近代の歌文では断定の「なり」との間に多少の混淆がある。"

Comment: @naruto
I updated description. Is it now good?

Comment: Yes, thank you!